# ** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Application tried to present a nil modal view controller on target

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview, uiimagepickercontroller

Trying to make a camera function to take a photo or choose an exciting photo. When I press "Infoga bild"(choose a exciting photo it crashes but when I take a new photo it works. But the image doesn't show in the image view.

Getting the error ** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Application tried to present a nil modal view controller on target 
*** First throw call stack:

I open the controller view from a tableview cell.

the code for the camera function:

```
#import "FMEImageview.h"
@implementation FMEImageview

- (IBAction)Tabild {
picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
picker.delegate = self;
[picker setSourceType:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera];
[self presentViewController:picker animated:YES completion:nil];


}

- (IBAction)Infogabild{
picker2 = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
picker2.delegate = self;
[picker2 setSourceType:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary];
[self presentViewController:picker animated:YES completion:nil];


}

- (void) imagePickerControllerDidCancel:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary*)info{

image = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];
[ImageView setImage: image];
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}

- (void) imagePickerControllerDidCancel:(UIImagePickerController *)picker {
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}

-(void) viewDidLoad {

[super viewDidLoad];

}

-(void) didReceiveMemoryWarning{

[super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
}

@end
```

The .h code:

```
@interface FMEImageview : UIViewController <UINavigationControllerDelegate, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate> {
UIImagePickerController *picker;
UIImagePickerController *picker2;
UIImage *image;

IBOutlet UIImageView *ImageView;

}

- (IBAction)Tabild;
- (IBAction)Infogabild;

@end
```

Thx in advance and i hope my code or question doesn't suck to much. I'm new to objective-c

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you're trying to presenting picker in Infogabild when the controller that you're creating there is named picker2.

Comment: Yeah you should probably advice him to dump instance variables he doesn't need.

Comment: and a single IBAction with a condition might have avoided the typo.

Comment: ye that worked! thank you verry much for the help! sometimes you stare yourself blind on the code. :)